# Divisibility Trick for 11

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to prove the 11 alternating sum divisibility trick. I know that $10\equiv -1\pmod{11}$ so for every power of $10$ in a number, we should be able to substitute in $(-1)$ like so:

$$ a(10^n) + b(10^{(n-1)}+\cdots+ c(10) + d \equiv a(-1)^{n} + b(-1)^{n-1}+\cdots+c(-1)+d\pmod{11}$$

What I am having trouble understanding is the fact that starting from the left, we are taking an alternating sum of the digits $(a - b + \cdots$ ). Since each power of $10$ will always become a power of $(-1)$, how can we always use an alternating sum from the left side? That seems like it would change the underlying nature of what is happening with the mod depending on whether we have an even or odd number of digits in the number. For example, when we have a three digit number $a(-1)^3+b(-1)^2+c = -a+b-c$ but according to the rule we have $a-b+c$ verses when we have a four digit number $a(-1)^4+b(-1)^3+c(-1)^2+d = a-b+c-d$ which works with the rule.

Am I missing something obvious? Do I possibly just have the alternating sum rule written incorrectly in my notes?

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you hear the rule that you alternate from the *left* rather than the *right*.  It does not matter for divisibility by $11$ as $0 = -0$.  but for finding the remainder, (ex.  $6824\equiv 4-2+8-6\equiv 4\pmod 11$) it does.

Comment: If you google the rule for divisibility, many websites specify that it must be from the left to the right. But I am not sure that it makes sense why it $must$ be from left to right or even why it $should$ be from left to right. That is why I asked this question.

Comment: Can you cite such a website?  I always heard "even" and "odd" positions and never specified from what direction.  If you do it in terms of even and odd *POWERS* then it will always work (if you are checking for remainders-- just divisibility it won't matter.)

Comment: https://math.hmc.edu/funfacts/divisibility-by-eleven/

Comment: That site *also* says "In fact, our observation shows more: that in fact when we take the alternating sum of the digits read from *right* to *left* (so that the sign of the units digit is always positive), then we obtain N mod 11."  It only suggested left to right because that's the natural way we read, from left to right.

Comment: Ah! I apologize! I did not see that earlier. Thanks!

Comment: Don't apologize.  I hadn't realized there were sites teaching from left to right.  I think that is a *very* poor practice as it only matters that you alternate.  It doesn't matter what direction you do it in. And..... dangit..... *saying* left to right is just weird to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You end with a $+$ for the final digit for the correct residue mod $11$. If you start from the left and pick the wrong sign for that but alternate anyway, it doesn't matter as the results will be each other's negative and if one is $0$ mod $11$ so is the other. So for divisibility it's equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You’re not computing the remainder modulo $11$, you’re only testing for divisibility by $11$, i.e. testing whether the remainder is $0$, so it doesn’t matter whether you change the sign, it will be still be $0$ in the same cases.

Comment: Yeah, but we *could* use this to test remainders.  $135 \equiv 4623\pmod{11} \iff 1-3+5 \equiv -4+6-2+3 \pmod {11}$.  There switching signs *would* matter as $3\not \equiv -3$.  But the OP *isn't* changing signs at all.  S/he is merely relabeling to variables so that what label for the even postions are now being use as labels for those in the odd (and vice versa).

Comment: @fleablood: No, the OP explicitly associates $a$ with the left-most digit ($10^n$) and explicitly states that the alternating sum starts from the left.

Comment: You're right.  In which case I think we need to tell the OP to alternate from the *right*.  I can't see any reason why going from the left should be written in stone.  The OP is correct that it gives a result that is the negative of going from the right (which won't matter for "Does it divide? Yes/No" determination; but will for "What is the remainder" calculations.)

Comment: @fleablood: The question was only about the divisibility test. People outside of mathematics are rarely interested in remainders, and are typically used to doing things from the left to the right, so the question whether and why the divisibility test works if you do it from left to right is a reasonable question.

Comment: I guess, but the OP is concerned the sites are claiming it *MUST* be left to right which it obviously doesn't.

Comment: @fleablood: OK, but that's an exchange in the comments that were written after I wrote this answer and after you commented on it.

Answer (score -3):

Why are you shifting the variable names.  You *can* but its confusing.  It=n $a(-1)^2 + b(-1)^1+c=a-b+c$ you have $a,c$ in the odd positions and $b$ in the even position.

But with $a(-1)^3+b(-1)^2+c(-1)^1 + d= -a+b-c+d$ you have $a,c$ switching to the *even* position, while $b$ switches to the odd.  And $d$ is new in the odd.

For less confusing to list from the right.

$a = a$ ($a$ in odd, nothing in even [divisible by $11$ if and only if $a = 0$])

$b(-1)^1 + a = -b + a$  ($a$ in odd; $a$ will *always* be in odd.  $b$ in even.)

$c(-1)^2 + b(-1)^1 + a = c - b + a$ ($a,c$ in odd; $b$ in even.)

$d(-1)^3 +c(-1)^2 +b(-1)^1 + a = -d + c -b+a$ ($a,c$ in odd; $b$ in even.... and so on.)

Comment: Are you suggesting alternating from the right side instead (where a will always be positive, b will be negative, and so on)?

Comment: Of course, why on earth would you alternate from the left?  The left will start with different powers of $(-1)$, sometimes even, sometimes odd.  It doesn't matter for divisibility (because $-0 = 0$) but it will for determining remainders.  $135\equiv 4623 \equiv 3\pmod {11}$ becasue $1-3+5\equiv -4+6-2+3\equiv 3\pmod {11}$.  But $1-3+5\not \equiv 4-6+2-3\pmod {11}$.  ($3 \not \equiv -3$.)